# Gnome Boxes Processor Count

Tags: cpu, gnome-boxes

VMWare Workstation 16 allows me to choose how many processors the VM may use.  Does Gnome Boxes have this same option?  I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it does have the same options.**

You will find the options when starting gnome boxes, either through your Desktop Environment or from the terminal using following command:

> gnome-boxes

Now you should be able to see the main window of gnome-boxes, right-click on your desired virtual machine and go to settings, you'll see on the first tab named 'ressources', in the first option there an option to set the CPU count (in an basic way).

If you want to configure more CPU options, go to the directory below and find your XML configuration file and edit it, maybe you'll need to reload your configuration through the `virsh` command or by restarting the virtualization service `systemctl restart libvirtd` command:

> cd ~/.config/libvirt/qemu

Please check the [KVM/QEMU CPU configuration page](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/qemu-cpu-models.html) for more information.